# How do I download audio from Instagram Reels?

Tags: instagram, audio

How can I efficiently download audio tracks from Instagram Reels for various purposes, such as creating content, personal projects, or simply for entertainment? I'm interested in exploring ways to extract audio clips from Reels without violating any copyright regulations.

Are there any reputable third-party apps or online tools that offer this functionality while ensuring compliance with Instagram's terms of service? Additionally, I'm curious about any step-by-step guides or tutorials that can assist me in navigating this process effectively. Any insights or recommendations would be highly appreciated, as I aim to responsibly utilize these audio resources for my creative endeavors.

Answer (score 0):

#### [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl)

If you are looking for a way to download media from Instagram Reels, you might want to try [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl). This is a command-line tool that can download any Instagram posts, including stories, highlights, and reels.

[To use gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl#user-content-installation), you need to have [Python](https://www.python.org/downloads/) installed on your computer, or you can download the [standalone executable file](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl#user-content-installation).

Once you have gallery-dl installed, you can open the command prompt and enter the following command:

```
gallery-dl --dest "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" --cookies-from-browser "Firefox" https://www.instagram.com/p/exampleURL/
```

This will download the media from the given Instagram post URL and, will save it in the “Downloads” folder on your computer (on Windows). You can change the destination folder by editing the `--dest` option in the command. It will use the cookies from your Firefox browser to access the profile. You can change the browser by modifying the `--cookies-from-browser` option.

The media from the Instagram post URL will be saved in subfolders named after the website and username. For the above example, a reel from “exampleusername” will be in `C:\Users\[Windows username]\Downloads\instagram\exampleusername`.

If you want to download all the media from an Instagram profile, you can simply provide the profile URL instead of a specific post URL. For example, if you want to download everything from the “exampleusername” account, you can use this command:

```
gallery-dl --dest "%USERPROFILE%\Downloads" --cookies-from-browser "Firefox" https://www.instagram.com/exampleusername
```